# Python one liner to merge dictionary which has common values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

**What I have:**

```
a=[{'name':'a','vals':1,'required':'yes'},{'name':'b','vals':2},{'name':'d','vals':3}]
b=[{'name':'a','type':'car'},{'name':'b','type':'bike'},{'name':'c','type':'van'}]
```

**What I tried:**

```
[[i]+[j] for i in b for j in a if i['name']==j['name']]
```

**What I got:**

```
[[{'name': 'a', 'type': 'car'}, {'name': 'a', 'vals': 1}], [{'name': 'b', 'type': 'bike'}, {'name': 'b', 'vals': 2}]]
```

**What I want:**

```
[{'name': 'a', 'type': 'car','vals': 1},{'name': 'b', 'type': 'bike','vals': 2}]
```

**Note:**

1. I need to merge dicts into one dict.
2. It should merge only those have common 'name' in both a and b.
3. I want python one liner answer.

Comment: What if a name occurs multiple times in one of the lists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Python 3, you can do this:

```
a=[{'name':'a','vals':1},{'name':'b','vals':2},{'name':'d','vals':3}]
b=[{'name':'a','type':'car'},{'name':'b','type':'bike'},{'name':'c','type':'van'}]

print([{**i,**j} for i in b for j in a if i['name']==j['name']])
```

Comment: Can you explain how this {**i,**j} merges into one dict ?

Comment: the ** is a splat operator for dictionaries. Essentially you're expanding key:value pairs out (of both dictionaries) and using it in the construction for the new dictionary. There's a bit more information here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-merging-two-dictionaries/

Comment: @ mahdilamb I need to know one more trick in this. I have updated my input in question. What if I want to remove one particular key,value from the merged result set. Here in this case 'required':'yes'. How to achieve this?

Comment: @Vanjith using dictionary comprehension

print([{k:v for k,v in {**i,**j}.items() if k!= "required" and v!= "yes"} for i in b for j in a if i['name']==j['name']])

Comment: @ mahdilamb Thank you! I found another solution already using 'pop'.

[{**i,**j}.pop("required") if {**i,**j}.get("required") else {**i,**j} for i in b for j in a if i['name']==j['name']]